# What is the lifetime of bluetooth data on the system bus?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, dbus, bluez

New to bluez & bluetooth. I have a few general questions about the management of data sourced from
a Polar sensor and written to the d-bus.

I'm working on a Jetson Nano that connects to a Polar heart rate sensor using Bluez.

When I worked in Data Warehousing I always pulled data from source systems by collecting data
where the source record's entry time stamp exceeded my last pull date. This prevented duplication
of data and missing new entries.

For this question, I consider the Jetson's d-bus as the source of my data. I pull from there.

Does this same concept I used in DW apply when pulling d-bus data? Is the d-bus data timestamped?
When data is read, is it read destruct, or should I delete it after I read it? Does data expire
and then automatically removed from the d-bus based on a built in timer? Is there a chance I would
miss data? Is there a mechanism (linux, d-bus, Bluez) to manage the life of the data?

Thanks for your assistance.  If you can provide a few clues or point me to some documentation it
would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A device stays on the dbus while it is connected and about 30 sec after disconnecting. Bonded devices stay forever. Data of a device is never removed as long as the device is there. Characteristic values or devices values are overwritten when new data comes in, i.e. a PropertiesChanged is received. So if you want to be informed of updates you need to subscribe to PropertiesChanged signals.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reconsider your view on the concept of D-Bus.

While the D-Bus has been developed for inter-process communication, a data warehouse is a central database optimized for analysis purposes.

They may share the same concepts in some aspects, but were developed for fundamentally different purposes and therefore behave very differently in key areas.